# How to use let with this LINQ query?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

Here is my LINQ query with multiple joins:

it is working good but I need to do an enhancement in its working.

```
    var selectedResults=
    from InvoiceSet in Invoices
    join BookedAreaSet in BookedAreas on InvoiceSet.InvoiceID equals BookedAreaSet.InvoiceID
    join AreaSet in Areas on BookedAreaSet.AreaID equals AreaSet.AreaID
    join ContactSet in Contacts on InvoiceSet.ContactID equals ContactSet.ContactID
    join Contacts_ObjectsSet in Contacts_Objects on ContactSet.ContactID  equals Contacts_ObjectsSet.ContactID
    join CompanySet in Companies on Contacts_ObjectsSet.ObjectReferenceID  equals  CompanySet.CompanyID
    join Customer_CustomerGroupSet in Customer_CustomerGroup on Contacts_ObjectsSet.ObjectReferenceID equals Customer_CustomerGroupSet.CustomerID
    join CustomerGroupDiscountsSet in CustomerGroupDiscounts on Customer_CustomerGroupSet.CustomerGroupID equals CustomerGroupDiscountsSet.ID
    join InvoiceStatusSet in InvoiceStatus on InvoiceSet.InvoiceStatusID equals InvoiceStatusSet.ID
    where Contacts_ObjectsSet.ObjectReference=="Company" 
//let minDate=(BookedAreaSet.LeasedDate).Min() where BookedAreaSet.InvoiceID=InvoiceSet.InvoiceID
    select new {licensee=(CompanySet.CompanyName),CustomerGroupDiscountsSet.CustomerGroup,AreaSet.Location,InvoiceSet.InvoiceNumber,InvoiceSet.Amount,InvoiceSet.TotalDiscount,InvoiceSet.GST,
    Paid=(InvoiceSet.InvoiceStatusID==2 ? "Paid":"UnPaid"), 
    datePaid=(InvoiceSet.PaymentDate),InvoiceSet.PaymentDate//,miDate



    };
```

In query I have commented what I want to add as well as commented in Select. From BookedArea table I want to get Minimum Leased Date for every invoiceID.

I just have started using LINQ so dont know how to do this.

Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var selectedResults=
    from InvoiceSet in Invoices
    join BookedAreaSet in BookedAreas on InvoiceSet.InvoiceID equals BookedAreaSet.InvoiceID
    join AreaSet in Areas on BookedAreaSet.AreaID equals AreaSet.AreaID
    join ContactSet in Contacts on InvoiceSet.ContactID equals ContactSet.ContactID
    join Contacts_ObjectsSet in Contacts_Objects on ContactSet.ContactID  equals Contacts_ObjectsSet.ContactID
    join CompanySet in Companies on Contacts_ObjectsSet.ObjectReferenceID  equals  CompanySet.CompanyID
    join Customer_CustomerGroupSet in Customer_CustomerGroup on Contacts_ObjectsSet.ObjectReferenceID equals Customer_CustomerGroupSet.CustomerID
    join CustomerGroupDiscountsSet in CustomerGroupDiscounts on Customer_CustomerGroupSet.CustomerGroupID equals CustomerGroupDiscountsSet.ID
    join InvoiceStatusSet in InvoiceStatus on InvoiceSet.InvoiceStatusID equals InvoiceStatusSet.ID
    where Contacts_ObjectsSet.ObjectReference == "Company"
    join BookedAreaSet2 in BookedAreas on InvoiceSet.InvoiceID equals BookedAreaSet.InvoiceID into BookedAreas2
    let minDate = BookedAreas2.Select(ba2 => ba2.LeasedDate).Min()
    select new
    {
        licensee = CompanySet.CompanyName,
        CustomerGroupDiscountsSet.CustomerGroup,
        AreaSet.Location,
        InvoiceSet.InvoiceNumber,
        InvoiceSet.Amount,
        InvoiceSet.TotalDiscount,
        InvoiceSet.GST,
        Paid = InvoiceSet.InvoiceStatusID == 2 ? "Paid" : "UnPaid", 
        datePaid = InvoiceSet.PaymentDate,
        InvoiceSet.PaymentDate,
        minDate,
    };
```